# Setting Java Heap Size for Spring boot project with embedded tomcat deployed as docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, heap-size

I have a spring boot REST application with embedded tomcat deployed in a docker container. My deployment YAML file has the following values set -

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 2.5G
  requests:
    memory: 512M

 env:
 - name: "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE"
   value: "dev"
 - name: "JAVA_OPTS"
   value: "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

and the docerfile is -

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
ARG ARTIFACT_NAME
WORKDIR /app
COPY $ARTIFACT_NAME /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app/app.jar
```

But the JVM heapsize is not getting set to 1G. I have even tried  using

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions 
-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap 
-XX:MaxRamFraction=2
```

but the result always shows MaxRamFraction as 4.

Comment: DId you `docker inspect` the image? Is the space before `env` accidental in SO or is it also present in your real file?

Comment: Yes I did inspect the pod and the memory allocations looks fine. Max heap size is set to 1/4 th of the available memory which I am not able to increase by changing the MaxRAMPercentage or MaxRamFraction or Xmx. The YAML file does not have any space issues, app is running fine.